# Is it correct to say "I'm not urgent to do something"?

Tags: adjectives, word-usage

I know it is correct to say "Something is not urgent for me". But it is correct to say

> I'm not urgent to do something.

If not, how do I state that I really want some problem to be resolved – maybe the problem is quite important in the future – but solving that problem is not urgent, and I would rather wait for some days or some weeks to find the best answer.  That is, "I" is the subject, and the object of the verb or term I'm seeking may be a long phrase with long clauses.

Comment: So you're looking for a way to say "it's not urgent" but with "I" as the subject?

Comment: Is "sth" appropriate for part of the title?  I'm guessing that's some sort of texting shorthand, but I had to open the question to find out what the question was asking.

Comment: Jimm Chen, because "sth" is not appropriate for part of a title, question, or answer, I changed it to "something".  Also, I edited the final paragraphs of the question; if inappropriately, you can revert or re-edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you unpack the word "urgent" then it comes across a bit better.

"I'm not in a hurry to do something" or "I'm in no rush to do something"

Comment: What does "unpack" mean?

Comment: @jwpat7 - I guess in this context I meant - expand the word to its meaning (or at least the particular meaning you are trying to convey).

Answer (score 2):

As already stated, "I'm not urgent..." is definitely not correct.

I would use the adverb form of "urgent".

> i.e. I must do this *urgently*.

Comment: How do you do something urgently?

Comment: I agree that when you think about it, it doesn't really make sense. But nonetheless it is a common phrase. "Do this urgently"- http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+this+urgently&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3 "Do it urgently"- http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+it+urgently&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: Or "Do this with urgency" - but that sounds a little stilted, to my ear.

Answer (score 2):

I would say: "It's not urgent that I [verb in the subjunctive]."

For example, "It's not urgent that I look into this matter right away" or "It's not urgent that he go so soon."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any native English speaker would have put it as "I'm not urgent..."

A more regular choice would be "something is not urgent for me...", as you have stated above.

Comment: Thank you. But I hope "I" can be the subject. [question edited.]

Comment: You would need to say "I'm not urgently required to do something," **but** the idiom to use really depends on what the "something" is. However, *urgent* always refers to the action which is urgent, not the person doing that action.

Answer (score 1):

"This isn't a priority for me." - That could work in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

A phrase like "proceed deliberately" may serve.  *[Deliberately](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deliberately)* has senses "Intentionally, or after deliberation; not accidentally." and "Taking one's time, slowly and carefully".  Another form is "with *[deliberation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deliberation)*" ("The act of deliberating, or of weighing and examining the reasons for and against a choice or measure; careful consideration; mature reflection" or "Careful discussion and examination of the reasons for and against a measure; as, the deliberations of a legislative body or council").

Examples:

> Let's proceed deliberately on something.
>   Something calls for deliberation.
>   I'm deliberating whether to something.

Numerous other circumlocutions exist, such as *carefully consider (or weigh)*, *thoroughly investigate (or discuss)*, *weigh our options (or alternatives)*.

Comment: Oops, your answer looking quite puzzling and something off topic.

Answer (score 0):

It's the matter that is urgent or not; it's not you that is the subject of urgency. Hence saying "I am not urgent ..." has the wrong subject. There are many different alternatives, including:
I'm not in a hurry/rush ...
I'm not eager to ...
I have no urgent need to ...
I'll do xxxx in my own good time ...
There's no urgency to ....
etc.